# Authenticate Using for webdriverjs

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How can you authenticate an authentication popup / alert with webdriverjs?

This solution would need to work on Chrome, FF, IE8-11, iOS Safari, and Android.

PhantomJS is not a consideration, so alerts are present.

This solution can not use credentials in url, as Safari on iOS deems it a phishing attack, and it has been deprecated from the url spec.